# Use of decorator pattern to decorate with only ONE behavior, is it valid?

Tags: java, validation, decorator

I have been reading on the user of decorator pattern and have a question to get clear about its usage. It seems decorator is applicable for cases when MULTIPLE layers of additional functionality are needed to be added on top of an EXISTING object.

The questions I have are:

1- is decorator pattern usage justified if we want to add only one behavior dynamically (rather than adding the behaviour to the class itself)?

2- As I understrand decorator is used for cases when functionality that is being added is somehow inherent/related to the to-be-decorated object. Is using decorator for validation of an object (which is a cross-cutting concern and not necessarily inherent to the object being validated a good option? I underastand .net uses decorators for some validations.

Thanks